# Procedure or function has too many arguments specified

Tags: c#, sql-server, vb.net

I have code that uses a stored proc, but I get the error stated in title. I have gone through similar posts but I dont get n fix. I have made sure the amount of parameters is the same as in the stored proc.

```
    @stype as varchar,
    @surl as varchar(500),
    @status as bigint,
    @pk_photo_id as bigint,
    @bactive as bigint,
    @property_id as varchar(30),
    @client_id as bigint   
.... rest of code
 if (@stype = 'L')
        BEGIN
            update ET_PROPERTY_PHOTO set sLarge_Url=@surl, idownloaded=@status where pk_Property_Photo_ID=@pk_photo_id
            if (@bactive=1)
            BEGIN
                update ET_PROPERTY set slarge_url=@surl where (Property_ID=@property_id) and (@client_id = fkl_XML_Client_ID)
            END
....rest of code
```

And my VB code:

```
    Dim cmdSet As New SqlCommand("ETSP_UPDATE_PHOTO_URLS")
    cmdSet.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    cmdSet.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stype", "L")

    Try

        Dim utility As New TransferUtility(AWSAccessKey, AWSSecretKey, RegionEndpoint.EUWest1)

        Dim S3_KEY As String = sKey
        Dim txtFolderPath As String = "C:\\images\\"
        Dim bucket As String = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings("bucket")

        Dim files As String() = Directory.GetFiles(txtFolderPath)

        For Each images As String In files
            Dim id As String = ""
            For Each str As String In IDS

                If Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(sKey).Contains(str) Then
                    id = str

                End If
            Next

            utility.Upload(txtFolderPath & sKey, bucket)
            Dim cannedACL As S3CannedACL = S3CannedACL.PublicRead


            Dim fileNameOnly As String = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(sKey)
            Dim token As String = fileNameOnly.Remove(fileNameOnly.LastIndexOf("_"c))
            Dim number As New String(token.SkipWhile(AddressOf [Char].IsLetter).ToArray())

            cmdSet.Parameters.AddWithValue("@surl", Convert.ToString("URL" & sKey))
            cmdSet.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status", 2)
            cmdSet.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pk_photo_id", number)
            cmdSet.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bactive", 1)
            cmdSet.Parameters.AddWithValue("@property_id", id)
            cmdSet.Parameters.AddWithValue("@client_id", clientIDs)
    ....code
```

Any Suggestions or fixes?
I dont mind c# help.

Comment: in which line is the error occurring?

Comment: Could it be due to adding the parameters in a loop?

Comment: @HackerMan Im not sure but when it want's to execute the code i assume, I have a log and it only comes up at the executeNonQuery, I cant debug, long story.

Comment: Also, your @stype parameter is never set.

Comment: @DavidBrabant: I made the same mistake, assumed it would be with the others, but it's set at the top of the function (line 3)

Comment: @DaveParsons if it that, how can I get around it? Do you thing if i use all the ` cmdSet.Parameters.AddWithValue(` in the loop it will work? I need it to execute it as many times as it can. I need to compare and update a lot. not only once?

Comment: you mean this? `cmdSet.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stype", "L")`?

Comment: @DavidBrabant it is "L" in one of the first lines.

Comment: @user3588641: each time the loop iterates you are adding all the parameters (except @stype) to the command object again. I'd probably just instantiate the command object within the loop so it's a new one each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding your parameters to the command for each image, but you are not using a new `SqlCommand` for each image. So when your loop starts work on the first image there are 1 parameter in the `SqlCommand`. Then you add 6 parameters (`surl` and co) and call the command. It has 7 parameters, all is well.

Then for the second image you add 6 parameters to the `SqlCommand` again on top of the 7 previous ones. Oops.

What you should do is instantiate the `SqlCommand` in the for loop in order to have the right parameters count at each call

```
Try

    Dim utility As New TransferUtility(AWSAccessKey, AWSSecretKey, RegionEndpoint.EUWest1)

    Dim S3_KEY As String = sKey
    Dim txtFolderPath As String = "C:\\images\\"
    Dim bucket As String = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings("bucket")

    Dim files As String() = Directory.GetFiles(txtFolderPath)

    For Each images As String In files
        Dim id As String = ""
        For Each str As String In IDS

            If Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(sKey).Contains(str) Then
                id = str

            End If
        Next

        utility.Upload(txtFolderPath & sKey, bucket)
        Dim cannedACL As S3CannedACL = S3CannedACL.PublicRead


        Dim fileNameOnly As String = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(sKey)
        Dim token As String = fileNameOnly.Remove(fileNameOnly.LastIndexOf("_"c))
        Dim number As New String(token.SkipWhile(AddressOf [Char].IsLetter).ToArray())

        Dim cmdSet As New SqlCommand("ETSP_UPDATE_PHOTO_URLS")
        cmdSet.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        cmdSet.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stype", "L")
        cmdSet.Parameters.AddWithValue("@surl", Convert.ToString("URL" & sKey))
        cmdSet.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status", 2)
        cmdSet.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pk_photo_id", number)
        cmdSet.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bactive", 1)
        cmdSet.Parameters.AddWithValue("@property_id", id)
        cmdSet.Parameters.AddWithValue("@client_id", clientIDs)
....code
```